# How to maintain state in autowired webservices?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, design-patterns

I have a design problem as follows: I want to execute several soap webservices, where each response depends on the former.
When all responses are obtained, I want to validate all obtained data, then build some output based on it, and also issue from DB update.

Therefore I created a `TemplateFacade` method that wrapps all webservices that are to be executed. Problem: I obviously have to persist the responses between the method calls. Which will be problematic as autowired services should by definition be stateless and are singletons.

So how can I use injection with services that have to maintain some kind of state (at least until the `Executor.execute()` has terminated)?

Could you recommend a better design approach?

```
@Component
class Executor {
    @Autowired
    TemplateFacade template;

    public void execute() {
        template.run();
        template.validate();
        template.buildOutput();
        template.updateDatabase();
    }
}

@Service
class TemplateFacade {
    //service classes wrapping webservice soap execution logic
    @Autowired
    PersonSoap personSoap;

    @Autowired
    CarSsoap carSoap;

    @Autowired
    ServiceDao dao;

    private WebserviceRsp personRsp, carRsp;

    void run() {
        personRsp = personSoap.invoke();
        //process response and prepare CarSoapXML accordingly, then send
        carRsp = carSoap.invoke();
    }

    //the following methods will all
    void validate() {
        //validate both responses
    }

    void buildOutput() {
        //create system out based on responses
    }   

    void updateDatabase() {
        dao.update(..);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share state between multiple web services, you could keep track using a PersonState in the session which is tied to the user. I recommend encryption or hashing to secure the information.

When the validate completes, you could keep a PersonState in the session. When the buildOutput starts, you could get the PersonState object and continue with your logic and so on.

It is important that, you keep the PersonState to have a smaller memory footprint. Incase of a  lot of data, you could just create a stateObject that will have the necessary state for the next step. e.g. at the end of validate you could create, BuildState object and put it in the session. build will get the object from the session and continue.

But I am not sure if it is really necessary to keep track of state and do it in 2 web services calls. The better solution would be to move all the logic part to another layer, and use the web services as just a window to your business/process layer.

Edit:

One more solution that could work you, is that the response of each step could contain the necessary state that is required for the next step. e.g. validateResponse contains personState and that could somehow be passed for the build.